# Bootstrap: Invisible checkbox with normal working inside button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap, meteor-react

In my React Meteor app that uses `react-bootstrap` npm package, I am trying to get a checkbox that looks like a button, [based on the code here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/jquery-checkbox-buttons) that nests the checkbox `input` and `i` elements within the `label.btn` element

However the following code renders out a button with a checkbox within the button.

[image]

How can we get rid of the checkbox box, such that the button looks like a regular button with only the icon and the text?

[image]

```
render() {

    ...

    <Row>
        <Col md={4} xs={12} xsOffset={1}>
            <form>
                <label className="btn btn-primary">
                    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                    <input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox
                </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use following css to hide this checkbox but keep performing normal operations:

```
label input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -10;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -10;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <label class="btn btn-primary custom-checkbox">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
    <input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox
  </label>
</form>
```